# How to add SINGLE QUOTE to each array element when pass to PHP via ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

I have created a drop down menu with checkbox options. The idea is when user select one or more checkboxes, the checked value should be passed to an SQL statement in a **php** page through AJAX. However, my sql does not seem to generate the result as it should be. My SQL statement is using an IN operator where the checked value should be inside the WHERE clause. For example, if I select CONSTRUCTION, HCL and RSS from the drop the menu checkboxes, the SQL statement in the **php** page should be `SELECT * FROM STAFF WHERE SERVICE IN ('CONSTRUCTION', 'HCL', 'RSS')`. However, when i echo my SQL statement, it was showing the checked values without the single quote - `SELECT * FROM STAFF WHERE SERVICE IN (CONSTRUCTION, HCL, RS)`which is incorrect. How can i include the single quotes for each checked values from the drop down for the IN operator? Can anyone help?

Below is my PHP and the drop down menu

**sql.php**

```
<?php

if($_POST['dataarray'] != ""){

$sql = "SELECT * FROM STAFF WHERE SERVICE IN (".$_POST['dataarray'].")";
.....
...
/*************SQL output*********************/
}

?>
```

**Drop Down Menu with checkboxes**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

/*********************convert select into multiselect************************/
$("#service").CreateMultiCheckBox({ width: '300px', defaultText : 'Select Below', height:'auto' }); 

    $("#service").on('change', function (){
                    var dataarray = [];
                
                    $("#service option").each(function(){
                        if($(this).is(":checked"))
                        {dataarray.push($(this).val());}    
                    }); 
                    
                    dataarray = dataarray.toString(); 
                 $.ajax({
                          url: "sql.php",
                          method:"POST",
                          data: {dataarray:dataarrayy},
                          success: function(data){                          
                          }             
                        });                 

                });
            
/**********************creating of checkboxes for each select option************************/
 $(document).on("click", ".MultiCheckBox", function () {
                var detail = $(this).next();
                detail.show();
            });

            $(document).on("click", ".MultiCheckBoxDetailHeader input", function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                var hc = $(this).prop("checked");
                $(this).closest(".MultiCheckBoxDetail").find(".MultiCheckBoxDetailBody input").prop("checked", hc);
                $(this).closest(".MultiCheckBoxDetail").next().UpdateSelect();
            });

            $(document).on("click", ".MultiCheckBoxDetailHeader", function (e) {
                var inp = $(this).find("input");
                var chk = inp.prop("checked");
                inp.prop("checked", !chk);
                $(this).closest(".MultiCheckBoxDetail").find(".MultiCheckBoxDetailBody input").prop("checked", !chk);
                $(this).closest(".MultiCheckBoxDetail").next().UpdateSelect();
            });

            $(document).on("click", ".MultiCheckBoxDetail .cont input", function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                $(this).closest(".MultiCheckBoxDetail").next().UpdateSelect();

                var val = ($(".MultiCheckBoxDetailBody input:checked").length == $(".MultiCheckBoxDetailBody input").length)
                $(".MultiCheckBoxDetailHeader input").prop("checked", val);
            });

            $(document).on("click", ".MultiCheckBoxDetail .cont", function (e) {
                var inp = $(this).find("input");
                var chk = inp.prop("checked");
                inp.prop("checked", !chk);

                var multiCheckBoxDetail = $(this).closest(".MultiCheckBoxDetail");
                var multiCheckBoxDetailBody = $(this).closest(".MultiCheckBoxDetailBody");
                multiCheckBoxDetail.next().UpdateSelect();

                var val = ($(".MultiCheckBoxDetailBody input:checked").length == $(".MultiCheckBoxDetailBody input").length)
                $(".MultiCheckBoxDetailHeader input").prop("checked", val);
            });

            $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
                var container = $(".MultiCheckBoxDetail");
                if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
                    container.hide();
                }
            });
        });

        var defaultMultiCheckBoxOption = { width: '220px', defaultText: 'Select Below', height: '200px' };

        jQuery.fn.extend({
            CreateMultiCheckBox: function (options) {

                var localOption = {};
                localOption.width = (options != null && options.width != null && options.width != undefined) ? options.width : defaultMultiCheckBoxOption.width;
                localOption.defaultText = (options != null && options.defaultText != null && options.defaultText != undefined) ? options.defaultText : defaultMultiCheckBoxOption.defaultText;
                localOption.height = (options != null && options.height != null && options.height != undefined) ? options.height : defaultMultiCheckBoxOption.height;

                this.hide();
                this.attr("multiple", "multiple");
                var divSel = $("<div class='MultiCheckBox'>" + localOption.defaultText + "<span class='k-icon k-i-arrow-60-down'><svg aria-hidden='true' focusable='false' data-prefix='fas' data-icon='sort-down' role='img' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 320 512' class='svg-inline--fa fa-sort-down fa-w-10 fa-2x'><path fill='currentColor' d='M41 288h238c21.4 0 32.1 25.9 17 41L177 448c-9.4 9.4-24.6 9.4-33.9 0L24 329c-15.1-15.1-4.4-41 17-41z' class=''></path></svg></span></div>").insertBefore(this);
                divSel.css({ "width": localOption.width });

                var detail = $("<div class='MultiCheckBoxDetail'><div class='MultiCheckBoxDetailHeader'><input type='checkbox' class='mulinput' value='-1982' /><div>Select All</div></div><div class='MultiCheckBoxDetailBody'></div></div>").insertAfter(divSel);
                detail.css({ "width": parseInt(options.width) + 10, "max-height": localOption.height });
                var multiCheckBoxDetailBody = detail.find(".MultiCheckBoxDetailBody");

                this.find("option").each(function () {
                    var val = $(this).attr("value");

                    if (val == undefined)
                        val = '';

                    multiCheckBoxDetailBody.append("<div class='cont'><div><input type='checkbox' class='mulinput' value='" + val + "' /></div><div>" + $(this).text() + "</div></div>");
                });

                multiCheckBoxDetailBody.css("max-height", (parseInt($(".MultiCheckBoxDetail").css("max-height")) - 28) + "px");
            },
            UpdateSelect: function () {
                var arr = [];

                this.prev().find(".mulinput:checked").each(function () {
                    arr.push($(this).val());
                });

                this.val(arr).change();
            },

});
```

```css
.MultiCheckBox {
            border:1px solid #e2e2e2;
            padding: 5px;
            border-radius:4px;
            cursor:pointer;
            background:#ffffff;
        }

        .MultiCheckBox .k-icon{ 
            font-size: 15px;
            float: right;
            font-weight: bolder;
            margin-top: -7px;
            height: 10px;
            width: 14px;
            color:#787878;
        } 

        .MultiCheckBoxDetail {
            display:none;
            position:absolute;
            border:1px solid #e2e2e2;
            overflow-y:hidden;
            background:#ffffff;
        }

        .MultiCheckBoxDetailBody {
            overflow-y:scroll;
        }

            .MultiCheckBoxDetail .cont  {
                clear:both;
                overflow: hidden;
                padding: 2px;
            }

            .MultiCheckBoxDetail .cont:hover  {
                background-color:#cfcfcf;
            }

            .MultiCheckBoxDetailBody > div > div {
                float:left;
            }

        .MultiCheckBoxDetail>div>div:nth-child(1) {
        
        }

        .MultiCheckBoxDetailHeader {
            overflow:hidden;
            position:relative;
            height: 28px;
            background-color:#3d3d3d;
        }

            .MultiCheckBoxDetailHeader>input {
                position: absolute;
                top: 4px;
                left: 3px;
            }

            .MultiCheckBoxDetailHeader>div {
                position: absolute;
                top: 5px;
                left: 24px;
                color:#fff;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="service" class="service" id="service">
  <option value="CONSTRUCTION">Construction</option>
  <option value="HCL">HCL</option>
  <option value="MANUFACTURING">Manufacturing</option>
  <option value="MYE">MYE</option>
  <option value="RSS">RSS</option>
  <option value="SERVICE">SERVICE</option>
  <option value="NA">NA</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Don't call `dataarray.toString()` in the ajax side, pass the array as is and quote the elements in the php side.

Comment: Do not insert the passed data directly in you sql statement. Just use prepared statements for this kind of database statements.

Comment: `data: {dataarray:dataarrayy}`
dataarrayy is not defined kindly correct the spell of datarrayy as dataarray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing there is very risky. You are putting the `$_POST` input directly into your sql-Query. This can lead to serious mysql-injections issues.

You should sanitize your `$_POST` data first. For instance use Methods like
`stripslashes` to remove unwanted characters that can lead to sql-injections.

Or use a database wrapper that uses prepared statements like [Pdo](https://www.php.net/manual/de/book.pdo.php)

To answer your String related question:

You can iterate over your data array and wrap the string with quotes:
E.g.

```
$dataArray = [];
foreach ($_POST['dataarray'] as $item) {
    $dataArray[] = "'" . $item . "'";
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM STAFF WHERE SERVICE IN (". implode(', ', $dataArray) .")";
```